# event for customer log record add after

Tags: customer, log

I'm trying to get Visitor Id of customer after customer registration success, and using event `customer_register_success` for this purpose. But this event may called earlier I think, because if I print data from `log_customer` table in this event, it doesn't show me the log record for the last current customer. But record is getting added to database. please suggest the right event to do the job done.

**EDIT :**

Just realized that customer log is getting updated in visitor _aftersave function

```
if ($this->_urlLoggingCondition->isLogEnabled()) {
    $this->_saveVisitorUrl($visitor);
    if ($visitor->getDoCustomerLogin() || $visitor->getDoCustomerLogout()) {
        $this->_saveCustomerInfo($visitor);
     }
}
```

But its called after customer_login so can't get it through this event & none of the other event is called after that (or I haven't fount one ?)

Answer (score 0):

If you see the customer controller createPost action you will notice that the event gets fired after successful creation of customer. The reason you are not getting customer id might be because the customer object passed in this dispatch event is same as the object this action received. That is why when you try to fetch Id you donot get the Id but are able to see the entry in db.

To resolve this problem, you can either fetch the id from customer email as below:

```
$customer_email = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer()->getEmail();
$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
$customer->loadByEmail($customer_email);
```

Or use a postdispatch event, something like this:

Where you have to replace controller_action with the controller and action name that you want. This will basically dispatch the event after the completion of action's execution.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: let me explain, the problem is not getting the Customer Id, I can get it into `customer_register_success` event. The issue is I can't get Visitor Id of the customer from `log_customer` table in the same event, and the question is which event is fired after `log_customer` table update

Thanks